# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset """

Tags: java, file-io, socket.io, connection, inputstream

I am tiring to send byte encrypted data over the socket, however, It does not work, the requirement is the server reads the key from file and receives an encrypted message from client
I am facing issues with Input/Output stream:I have used one variable that read file and sockets.

Server Code

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.security.*;
    import java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter;
    import java.security.KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry;

   import javax.crypto.*;
   import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

   public class CipherServer
  {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    int port = 7999;
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket s = server.accept();

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("KeyFile.xx"));
    
    // YOU NEED TO DO THESE STEPS:
    // -Read the key from the file generated by the client.
    SecretKey desKey = (SecretKey)in.readObject();

    // YOU NEED TO DO THESE STEPS:
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    
    in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    byte[] cipherText;
            
    cipherText= (byte[]) in.readObject();


    // -Use the key to decrypt the incoming message from socket s.  
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);

     CipherInputStream cipherIn = new CipherInputStream(s.getInputStream(), cipher);

    System.out.println("Algorithm used to generate key : "+desKey.getAlgorithm());   

    byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);


    // -Print out the decrypt String to see if it matches the orignal message.
    System.out.println(plaintext.toString());       



}
 }
```

Client Code

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;

   import javax.crypto.*;

   public class CipherClient
  {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    // YOU NEED TO DO THESE STEPS:
    // -Generate a DES key.
    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

    // -Store it in a file. 
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("KeyFile.xx"));  
    out.writeObject(desKey);   


    String message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
    int port = 7999;
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
    
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    //convert the massage to bits
    byte[] messa= message.getBytes();

    // -Use the key to encrypt the message above and send it over socket s to the server.   
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);

    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(messa);  
    System.out.println(new String(cipherText));

    // YOU NEED TO DO THESE STEPS:
   //  ObjectOutputStream.reset(cipherText);
    out.write(cipherText);

  }
   }
```

I receive an ERROR Message at the server side

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
     at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
     at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
     at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:200)
     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2802)
     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:3129)
     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3139)
     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1619)
     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
     at DES.CipherServer.main(CipherServer.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the write side, you are calling OutputStream.write(byte[]), on the read side, you are calling readObject (then trying to convert that to a byte[]). If you are going to use ObjectStreams (which I highly discourage) you need to be consistant with writeObject and readObject on both sides